# Concatenate String and Pipeline Variable in Azure DevOps Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a Azure Release Pipeline which is used to deploy the non-production data factory template to the production data factory used in a migration. This pipeline will be specific to a team that needs to be migrated.

Given that the team name is used in multiple places in the pipeline, I wanted to make it a pipeline variable and concatenated with the required template name and database name in the override template parameters.

I'm unsure how to get this pipeline variable to concatenate with a string value. I've tried this:

```
-factoryName $(TeamName)+"MattersphereEngageProd"
```

But it produces this result `FERL"MattersphereEngageProd"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want `FERLMattersphereEngageProd` you can use:

```bash
-factoryName "$(TeamName)MattersphereEngageProd"
```